# Some web sites can not be reached

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

With my laptop running an arch-linux I can not access some websites *when I am at home* like for example:

- https://www.wikipedia.org/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/
- https://www.leo.org/

But I can access those websites from university as well as from my parents' place.

There are some websites that I *can* access from home like for example:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- https://www.startpage.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/

This is independent of whether I use Qutebrowser or Firefox.

An old debian system installed as dual boot on the same laptop is able to access all of those websites from home.

When I am trying to access a not working website Firefox says:

> Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.
>
> We can’t connect to the server at www.leo.org. If that address is
>   correct, here are three other things you can try:
>
> - Try again later.

I have done that plenty of times.

> - Check your network connection.

I am connected and I have an ip address.

> - If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.

I am able to access other webpages and why should a firewall forbid wikipedia but allow youtube?

I am able to ping those webpages from my arch system via ip but not via url.
Therefore I am assuming a DNS problem.

According to `dig` my DNS server is my router, which is the same for another debian system in the same network where everything is running fine.

I am using `systemd-resolved`.

I am lost how to debug this further. Why does it work elsewhere but not at home? Why does it work on other systems in the same network but not on my arch linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check file /etc/nsswitch.conf. It is name service switch configuration file. Param. *host* in this file shows you sources which systemd-resolved uses for getting host by name.

Comment: that's it. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contained `hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns` after removing the `[!UNAVAIL=return]` it works. Thank you very much. Just out of curiosity, do you know the reasoning why it was in there? My debian system has a `[NOTFOUND=return]` instead. If I insert that on my arch linux I can not access those pages again.